# Refresh a link from my python script

Tags: python, refresh

I have a link for example www.google.com and i want it to be refreshed from my python script after every 2 seconds. Is there an inbuilt function in python to do this or can anyone help me out with the code.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh? Refresh what?

Comment: ctrl+r is what i am to referring to .I need that to be done automatically from the script ,without me pressing the refresh button of the browser

Comment: Javascript would probably be a better option for this.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 Answer for Windows:

```
import ctypes
from time import sleep

SendInput = ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput

# C struct redefinitions 
PUL = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
class KeyBdInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("wVk", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("wScan", ctypes.c_ushort),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class HardwareInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("uMsg", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("wParamL", ctypes.c_short),
                ("wParamH", ctypes.c_ushort)]

class MouseInput(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dx", ctypes.c_long),
                ("dy", ctypes.c_long),
                ("mouseData", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwFlags", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("time",ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("dwExtraInfo", PUL)]

class Input_I(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_ = [("ki", KeyBdInput),
                 ("mi", MouseInput),
                 ("hi", HardwareInput)]

class Input(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("type", ctypes.c_ulong),
                ("ii", Input_I)]

# Actuals Functions

def PressKey(hexKeyCode):

    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( hexKeyCode, 0x48, 0, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):

    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( hexKeyCode, 0x48, 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


def RefreshPage():
    while True:
        PressKey(0x11) # Control
        PressKey(0x52) # R
        ReleaseKey(0x52)
        ReleaseKey(0x11) 
        time.sleep(2)
```

To find out other key codes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: where do i enter my link that will get refreshed after the set time given as input by me?

Comment: I seem to be misunderstanding your question. I thought you had mentioned you wanted to use Ctrl + R to refresh your page.

Comment: I am new to python frankly speaking I did not understood your code properly . Btw I wanted an automatic refresh for a specific link . lets's say i have a youtube video and i want the page to reload again after 2 minutes or so .Can that be done from a python script.